# Azure Service Fabric Mesh template secure access

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

How can I use a Service Fabric Mesh template that is in a secure location such as a private Azure blob?

So far there seems to be very little documentation around the template itself and all of the examples utilize a template stored on a publicly accessible server.

Comment: this question and answer are completely useless as they are extremely specific. if you would want to find such information you would probably search for: "how to reference local parameters file in arm template". also, this is pretty useless, you want automation anyway, automation cannot be on your local computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I found to do this is to use the --template-file parameter instead of the --template-url parameter. This allows you to reference a local file on the machine running the deployment.